# Context manager to keep Django views clean?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have already asked similar question, but that was too broad and not Django-specific. Is a good practice to keep Django views clean with context managers to make a code DRY? This is example of code (a bit pseudocode):

```
class DjangoViewset():
    @action(method=['GET'])
    def custom_action1(request):
        a = get_data_from_somewhere1()
        b = get_data_from_somewhere2()
        if a<b:
            raise 400
        if a==1:
            raise 404
        if a==2:
            raise 403 
        result = some_complicated_logic(a, b)
        return Response(result)

    @action(method=['GET'])
    def custom_action2(request):
        a = get_data_from_somewhere1()
        b = get_data_from_somewhere2()
        if a<b:
            raise 400
        if a==1:
            raise 404
        if a==2:
            raise 403
        result = some_complicated_logic_another(a, b)
        return Response(result)
```

Can I refactor it with something like this or this is bad using of context manager?

```
@contextmanager
def validate_data(a, b):
    if a<b:
        raise 400
    if a==1:
       raise 404
    if a==2:
       raise 403
   yield

class DjangoViewset():
    @action(method=['GET'])
    def custom_action1(request):
        a = get_data_from_somewhere1()
        b = get_data_from_somewhere2()
        with validate_data(a, b):
            result = some_complicated_logic(a, b)
        return Response(result)

    @action(method=['GET'])
    def custom_action2(request):
        a = get_data_from_somewhere1()
        b = get_data_from_somewhere2()
        with validate_data(a, b):
            result = some_complicated_logic_another(a, b)
        return Response(result)
```

With this refactor code looks much simpler, but I can't find information if I can use context manager this way, but is it not forbidden style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why context managers should be used for this purpose - you don't get any of their benefits by using them here. Simply calling

```
validate_data(a, b):
result = some_complicated_logic_another(a, b)
```

should be enough, relying on `validate_data` raising an error if necessary.

But since you mentioned, you are using Django rest framework, to me this seems a good use for [Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) and using their validation system. Assuming of course, that your `get_data_from_somewhere1` use `request` data as input (at least partially).
To call serializer validation, you can call `is_valid`, e.g.

```
serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data, context=...)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Then inside serializer's `validate` function, you raise appropriate exceptions, using the status codes you want, e.g. `ValidationError('my error msg')` (from `rest_framework.exceptions`).

Or you could simply raise `ValidationError` (or extend it to override its default `status_code`, if you need to) from your `validate_data()` functions.

Comment: 1. DRF validation is not called on GET, as i showed in `action` declaration. 2. If I replace it with function - function can't make a response with selected status code? How u suppose my view will look with your proposal?

Comment: @Chiefir I have edited my answer and added examples of how to use serializer validation in your case

Comment: DRF has exception handler for ApiExceptions that send appropriate 4xx codes - or codes you define/want

Comment: as i said DRF validation is not fired on `GET` method, so I can't use it in this case.

Comment: for example this is a case when I `GET` a model instance, check its date field, and if date exceeded - I want to raise `404`. I can't fire any built-in validation method here.

Comment: @Chiefir You **can** call serializer's `is_valid()` method even in GET requests and when you raise a `ValidationError` inside them, it properly handles them and returns proper error response.

Comment: ok, i have tried as u told - `invitation = self.get_object(); serializer = self.get_serializer(invitation);       serializer.is_valid()` and get `AssertionError: Cannot call '.is_valid()' as no 'data='keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.`

Comment: You are not using DRF as you are supposed to. You are supposed to call `is_valid(raise_exception=True)` and serializer with `data={...}` parameter. However I've offered a simpler alternative at the end of my answer, seeing that you don't really need serializers here.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is a bad use of a context manager since its not providing any real context. Normally a context manager would provide some context like a database connection or a file handle which requires work to be done when entering and exiting the context (eg opening and closing the database connection).

Why not just put the validation logic inside a regular function?

```
def validate_data(a, b):
    if a<b:
        raise 400
    if a==1:
       raise 404
    if a==2:
       raise 403
```

then do

```
    validate_data(a, b):
    result = some_complicated_logic(a, b)
```

In your view, and you know that the data has been validated when preforming the logic.

Comment: the problem is that if it a usual function - I can't raise error with specific http code - it is always code `500`. But I want return other codes.

Comment: Then make `validate_data` return the error code you want, and then raise an error with that code from your view

Comment: but what if I also return a specific error message connected to a status code? And I have to check if `validate_data` returned any int, than make a return...  The code still grows, while with context manager it is DRY and small?